# How to find delta of 2 dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find not common data from 2 data frame.

**df1**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'contact_id': [1,2,3,4]
})

   contact_id
0           1
1           2
2           3
3           4
```

**df2**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'contact_id': [1,3,4,5]
})

   contact_id
0           1
1           3
2           4
3           5
```

**Expected output**

```
   contact_id
0           2
1           5
```

I have tried to use below code but getting incorrect

```
df = df2[~df2.contact_id.isin(df1.contact_id)]
```

Can anyone help me how can I get expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `merge()` with `indicator=True` and then filter out values by using `query()` finally drop extra column by using `drop()`:

```
out=(df1.merge(df2,indicator=True,on='contact_id',how='outer')
        .query("_merge!='both'").drop('_merge',1))
```

output of out:

```
   contact_id
1       2
4       5
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,
you can merge two datasets , drop duplicates and the index. If you want to keep the index then remove the reset_index method.

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False).reset_index(drop =True)
```